# Android OpenOptionsMenu not updating after firing off once

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, baseadapter, android-optionsmenu

First off I have a baseadapter for a listview and each row has a unique message.I am trying to get OpenOptionsMenu to update after an OnClick event but what is happening is that after the 1st Onclick event that same message is posted over and over again ignoring the new messages. I have a toast inside that Onclick event and that toast displays a new message for each row that is clicked, so it is either that my SharedPreferences is not updating or my OpenOptionsMenu is not updating after that first click.

```
   //inside BaseAdapter
    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
              // This is a unique value depending on the row clicked
                String mm=jsonObject.getString("post");

                SharedPreferences userInfo= m.getSharedPreferences("userInfo", m.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= userInfo.edit();
                editor.putString("share",mm);
                editor.commit();
          // This does not update after the first click
                m.openOptionsMenu();
      // can confirm here that new value is added after every OnClick
                Toast.makeText(m.getApplicationContext(),"New Values: "+mm,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               Toast.makeText(m.getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
    });
```

The reason why I am doing this is because I am incorporating the android easy share action http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html and am prefilling it with the data from the rows in the listview. The OnCreateOptionsMenu looks like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        MenuItem shareItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        SharedPreferences   sp_myaccount = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String acc=   sp_myaccount.getString("share", "");
        System.err.println("uud: " + acc);
Toast.makeText(LocalFeed.this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ShareActionProvider  mShare= (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();
        Intent ShareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        ShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        ShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        ShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, acc);
        mShare.setShareIntent(ShareIntent);
        return true;
    }
```

Noticed that I have a toast message in there too and can confirm that it only fires off on the first Onclick event. This is what a typical prefilled message looks like
[image]

I have done some more testing and I am pretty sure that the issue is with

```
  m.openOptionsMenu();
```

is there a way to possibly refresh that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [invalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) which will force `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be called again. It is available since api level 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked appreciate it, just had to put                    m.openOptionsMenu();
                  m.invalidateOptionsMenu();